# APK error build in IONIC

Tags: android, build, ionic2, apk

I have tried to build apk for android in IONIC however everytime I do the build using command: `ionic cordova build android` it will always result to BUILD FAILED. The error is so generic it only says DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. Below image is the full response:
[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to open android studio->Tools->Android->SDK Manager
[See the screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuwM4.png)

And Applying at the time, it will ask the license. You have to accept and download the API 26. After it will work. :)

Comment: Done downloading API 26 and trying to build again and now have this error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Comment: error with this as well: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka io.ionic.starter:string/fb_app_id) not found.
bec we are using fb login api

Comment: You have to add the facebook App ID in package.json
 "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "1234567890",
        "APP_NAME": "Your App Name"
      },

Answer (score 0):

Unhandle Promise rejection comes mainly with Cordova version @8.0.0.

Could you downgrade the version to 7 to 6 and try to build ?